# Wpf how to print ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I would like to know what is the easiest way to print ListBox's values. I have tried to use FlowDocumentReader but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to print a visual element,you can use

```
             PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
             printDlg.PrintVisual(ListBox1, "Listbox Printing.");
```

It can be used to print any visual object(any control, container, Window or user control)

If you are looking to print the items only then you can use the FlowDocument

```
             FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
             foreach (object item in items)
             {
                 fd.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(item.ToString())));
             }
             fd.Print();
```

or

```
             PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
             pd.PrintDocument(fd);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer biju it was really informative and that second alternative is exactly what I'm looking for. However, now I get "System.Xml.XmlElement" from all my items. I think it is because of calling objects ToString() method, but how to overcome it? I have StackPanel with XmlDataProvider and ListBox inside it. And ListBox's ItemsSource is from XmlDataProvider.

Comment: Try fd.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(XmlElement.InnerText.ToString())));