# Print large datas in List box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some issues to print a large value using  "printDlg.PrintVisual("lblView","List box printing").Only the first part of the list which is visble  only comes in the printed document.Some part is clippped.

How can I print entire rows?

I have an List box in my WPF application I am populating large datas to this list Box.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,2,2,2" ItemsSource="{Binding datas}" 
                  Visibility="{Binding Checked,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToNegationVisibility}}"
                 x:Name="lblView" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="12" >
................
............
</listox>
```

please advice

Thanks in advance,

Roshil

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot of what it looks like in the application and what it look likes when you print it?

Comment: Hi Jordy van Eijk,Due to some security reasons I couldnt able to put the screen shot here.But Hope you can  understand the Situtaion>I am binding nearly 400 rows to the List box.So when I am going to print the list box content using "Printvisual" I am getting only first 10 or 14 rows.

Comment: Does this help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522038/wpf-how-to-print-listbox

Comment: You can try to expand the size of the control for printing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
 printDlg.PrintVisual(ListBox1, "Listbox Printing.");
```