# How to print listbox contents using C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, listbox

I am using C# WPF (trying to use MVVM) with GalaSoft.MvvmLight. In my View I have a list box

```
 <ListBox x:Name="OutputListBoxWindow" 
                 Grid.Row="5"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
                 Margin="5,5,5,5"
                 Height="Auto"
                 Background="Black"
                 Foreground="LimeGreen"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding OutputListBox}" 
                 SelectedIndex="{Binding OutputListBoxIndex}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding Enable, Mode=OneWay}" 
                 AutomationProperties.IsColumnHeader="False">
```

I also have a print button

```
<Button
            Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="6"
            
            Command="{Binding PrintCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=OutputListBoxWindow, Mode=OneWay}"

            Content="Print" 
            Margin="20,15,20,15"/>
```

I have put what I believe to be the Visual (the item I want to print) in as a CommandParameter.

In my ViewModel I have a RelayCommand not ICommand

```
public RelayCommand<Visual> PrintCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<Visual>(vdata =>
                {
                    PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(myPrintDialog.ShowDialog()))
                    {
                        myPrintDialog.PrintVisual(vdata, "listbox contents Printing.");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I put a breakpoint in at the line with PrintVisual and I can see that I have hold of the ListBox as it knows how many lines of data I have. If I continue I get the print dialog. I then choose print to PDF and give it a name. It does create a file but what I get appears to be the main window minus the ListBox. I think at the bottom of the PDF I get just a few pixels of the ListBox as shown below.
[![PDF printout][1]][1]
Thinking it was a ListBox issue I tried to print a TextBlock but now I get a blank. Not sure if it helps but in the Print dialog I choose to have A4 paper etc. The print I get is not A4 and seems to be the size of something else. I was expecting an image inside the A4. What have I missed here please.

Printing PDF from Notepad works so the PDF print driver is working

**Update:** This is what I think is happening. If I put a name in the the window tag and then print that I get the whole window in full colour. If I put a name in a control and try and print that I get the issue. Looking at it further I saw that I know I have hold of the control and I know its size so I know what size I will print. Here is the issue instead of picking up the correct corner to start to print from it picks up the incorrect corner and start to measure from that. This is why in my image above the top is blank and the bottom has just the start of my list box. I tried this with many different controls and they all print but from an entirely different part of the window. At this stage I have no idea how to fix this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8GmQ.png

Comment: Have you considered the alternative mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524156/1136211

Comment: Did not get anything in the article to help. I think the article is pure WPF rather than MVVM. I can see in my MVVM I have to pass the Visual (ListBox) across to the ViewModel and this I seem to be doing. I added name to main window <Window x:Name="ABC" and printed that and it came out perfectly.  Looks like although I have the ListBox in the Modelview what I print is everything other than the Listbox although I only passed the listbox to the modelview not the whole window. MVVM is a kind of magic for me still.

Comment: Since you're passing visual into a command this is not MvvM, which BTW is an ICommand, that RelayCommand implements that interface, otherwise it would not work. Clemens' comment is at least worth giving a go. I would put an interface on a control so you can mock it later.